# Trying to connect to a redis client from nuxt 3 middleware but the connection is undefined

Tags: vue.js, redis, middleware, nuxt3

i am trying to connect to a redis server to get my session data from  a nuxt 3 defineNuxtRouteMiddleware middleware and am not having success. i create the connection to redis in a server side plugin and it works in all my api endpoints however it does not seem to work in my middleware for rout-guards . i attempt to get the connection in the code bellow but the connection is undefined. am i incorrect in assuming that the middleware serverside execution should have access to the redis connection

```
if (process.server) {
 let session = await RedisUtil.getConnection.get(sessionID);
}
```

bellow is the redisUtil

```
class RedisUtil{
    static get getConnection(){
        return this.connection;
    }

    static set setConnection(connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    static async connect(config) {
        let redis = createClient({
            url: 'redis://' + config.redis.user + ':' + config.redis.password + '@' + config.redis.host + ':' + config.redis.port
        });

        redis.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

        await redis.connect();
        RedisUtil.setConnection = redis;
        console.log("Connected to redis");
    }
}
```

the redis plugin is loaded into the nitro config

```
import RedisUtil from '../utils/RedisUtil';
import config from "~/server.config"
export default async (NuxtApp) => {
    await RedisUtil.connect(config);
};
```

```
    nitro: {
        plugins: [
                "~/server/plugins/redis.js"
            ],
    },
```

as stated above i am able to access the redis connection in all other server side executions but not in the middleware. any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're only running the Redis request during the server side part. Making it lose context when client side routing happens.

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  let session = '';
  if (process.server) {
    session = 'has some context';
  }

  // server: session = 'has some context'
  // client: session = ''
})
```